# Realigning GPT partitions to 4k sector boundaries?

Tags: partition, utilities, gpt

If I have an HDD with GPT, and the partitions are not aligned to 4k sector boundaries, is there a tool to realign the partitions to 4k sector boundaries?

Suppose I have UEFI stuff on the HDD in question, but I don't need to boot from it right now (I have another boot HDD). However, I need it to still be bootable correctly after realignment.